# VBA Excel Click on a Label

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I am currently doing excel IE Automation where I want to click label on webpage.

The HTML source code is:

```
<td class = t19TabItem><a href="javascript:apex.submit('D_Price');">Compliance</a></td>
```

Any help to click on label compliance.

I used the below code, has found the label compliance by using inner html, but it does not click on compliance tab. It throws errors as object does not this property.

```
set link=IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
if link.InnerHTML="compliance" and link.href="javascript:apex.submit('D_Price')" then
    click link
end if
```

How to click on compliance label?

Comment: html source code for above question

<td classname = t19tabItem><a href="javascript:apex.submit('D_Price');">Compliance</a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code with references below

> Microsoft HTML Object Library
>
> Microsoft Internet Controls**

```
Sub test()
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim ie As Variant
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "your web link" 'Your weblink goes here
While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_LOADED
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If oHTML_Element.innerHTML = "compliance" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot karthick for your quick help :-). It's working.

Comment: Then please mark it as a solution(by check the tick mark). so that it will be useful for other developers too to find the solution code.

Comment: Can you please give me some reference as how to choose type for declaring variables/elements/objects in excel vba, as i am encountering frequent error "object doesn't support this property or method" .

for example, as you mentioned in your answer as 
Dim oHTML_Element as IHTMLElement .